# Transverse field Ising model - why is the sum restricted to half of the Brillouin zone?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, crystals, ising-model

I am reading Coleman's "Introduction to many-body physics" and am working on problem 4.2, which involves calculating the spectrum of the transverse-field Ising model.

We start with the Hamiltonian
$$ H = -J \sum_{j} S^{x}_{j} S^{x}_{j+1} -h \sum_{j} S^{z}_{j}.   $$
I have successfully used a Jordan-Wigner transformation to turn it into fermion creation/annihilation operators as
$$ H = \sum_j \left( \frac{J}{4}\left(f_jf_{j+1}+f_jf^{\dagger}_{j+1}-f_j^{\dagger}f_{j+1}-f_j^{\dagger}f_{j+1}^{\dagger}   \right)-hf_j^{\dagger}f_j\right).$$  Then I Fourier transformed this Hamiltonian to get $$H = \sum_k \left(Ad_k^{\dagger}d_k -\frac{Ji\sin{ka}}{4}\left(d_kd_{-k}+d_k^{\dagger}d_{-k}^{\dagger}\right)   \right),$$
where $A = -\frac{J}{2}\cos{ka}-h$.

The textbook says the sum should be only over half of the Brillouin zone $k\in[0,\pi/a]$, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

After the Jordan-Wigner transformation, in the fermionic picture, there is one particle per site. So Fermi surface will enclose half the Brillouin zone. That's we sum only over the half Brillouin region.